# Silent Install of DataStax Cassandra Community Edition from Windows Server fails

Tags: windows, installation, cassandra, silent, datastax-enterprise

I am using the datastax-community-64bit_1.2.5.msi for installing on Windows VM. I am using the silent install command

> msiexec /i
>   C:\ddapplications\cassandra\datastax-community-64bit_1.2.5.msi /quiet
>   /qn /le C:\ddapplications\cassandra\installlog.txt

If I run the installation command from the command line it installs as expected. No issues.
If I run the command from a Windows Service that runs as LocalSystem, I get the following error. 
Is this a known issue? Is there a workaround? I also manually tried creating a group named WORKGROUP and adding the SYSTEM user to that group. 
The SYSTEM user exists in the VM.

> === Logging started: 6/7/2013  23:52:23 === Error 1609. An error occurred while applying security settings. WORKGROUP\SYSTEM is not a
>   valid user or group. This could be a problem with the package, or a
>   problem connecting to a domain controller on the network. Check your
>   network connection and click Retry, or Cancel to end the install.
>   Unable to locate the user's SID, system error 1332
>   === Logging stopped: 6/7/2013  23:52:25 ===

Answer (score 2):

Is your VM in a domain? What is the service that you are using to trigger the installer running as?

A possible workaround may be to make that service run as Administrator.